# Passing arguments down to nested functions Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for the newb question here, but Im new to javascript. Ideally I would like to call for myLoop(latLong); but unless I make the variables outside of the function, I can't seem to have .setPosition() recognize the variable.

```
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var z = 0;
    var v = 0;

    function xy(a,b,c,d) {
        var longDistance = Math.abs(a-d);
        var longTime = longDistance/0.1*0.5;            
        var latDistance = b-c;
        var latRate = latDistance/longTime*0.5;
        x = a; //origin long
        y = b; //oringin lat
        z = latRate;
        w = d; //destination long
        v = c; //destination lat
    }

    function myLoop () {        
        setTimeout(function () {
            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
            marker.setPosition(latLong); 
            x = x + 0.1;
            y = y - z;
            if (x < w && y < v) { 
                myLoop();
            } else {

                alert('finished');

            }
        }, 0.5)
    }

    xy(-118,33,40,-73);
    myLoop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You simply need to pass the `latLong` variable into the `myLoop()` function recursively.

To do this, you can create your first latLong variable outside of the function, then call the function (passing in the first latLong variable), then within the latLong function, check for your conditions, and if you need to call the myLoop function again, update the latLong variable and then call the myLoop function again.

Here is what your recursive code would look like:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
var v = 0;

// Your first latLong
var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);

function xy(a,b,c,d) {
    // ...
}

// Pass in the latLong variable
function myLoop (latLong) {        
        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.setPosition(latLong); 
            x = x + 0.1;
            y = y - z;
            if (x < w && y < v) { 
                
                // now create a new latLong, and pass it 
                // back into this function recursively
                latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
                myLoop(latLong);

            } else {
                alert('finished');
            }
        }, 0.5)
    }

xy(-118,33,40,-73);

// Now call the myLoop function to get the recursion started
myLoop(latLong);
```

#### Alternatively, you can wrap all the code up into one function

Using the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), you can wrap up all your loop functionality in one place (within a function object called `latLongGenerator`), allowing for a nice separation in your code logic, but still giving you a clean interface to use. The restructured "revealing module" code would look like this:

```
var latLongGenerator = (function () {
    
   var x = 0;
   var y = 0;
   var z = 0;
   var v = 0;
   var latLong;
    
   function setXY(a,b,c,d) {
      var longDistance = Math.abs(a-d);
      var longTime = longDistance/0.1*0.5;            
      var latDistance = b-c;
      var latRate = latDistance/longTime*0.5;
      x = a; //origin long
      y = b; //oringin lat
      z = latRate;
      w = d; //destination long
      v = c; //destination lat
      
      // pass in the initial latLong to myLoop(latLong) from here
      latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
      myLoop(latLong);
    }
    
    // This is the only function that will
    // be exposed publicly on this function
    // Example usage: latLongGenerator.startLoopWith(0,0,0,0);
    function startLoopWith(a,b,c,d){
       setXY(a,b,c,d);
       
    }
    
    function myLoop (latLong) {        
        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.setPosition(latLong); 
            x = x + 0.1;
            y = y - z;
            if (x < w && y < v) {
                // recursively call the loop from here
                latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(y,x);
                myLoop(latLong);
            } else {
                alert('finished');
            }
        }, 0.5);
    }
    
    return {
        startLoopWith:startLoopWith
    };
    
})();

// Finally, you can start your loop by passing in
// your initial values to latLongGenerator.startLoopWith(...)
latLongGenerator.startLoopWith(-118,33,40,-73);
```

This structure gives you a clean way of encapsulating all your calculation logic, while also giving you a nice, clean entry point. Using this new refactor, you can get your loop started with one line:

```
latLongGenerator.startLoopWith(-118,33,40,-73);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should help you get on the right track.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know that my question sounds very bad because thats the most obvious answer, but it doesn't work.  Ideally, I wouldn't need to have the x,y,z,v variables outside of the function... I would like to function to accept all the arguments so that all I have is the myLoop function.

Comment: ok @user1724492, see if my updated answer helps. I added a new alternative.